# How to replace null by "NULL" in a List<string> without foreach loop?

Tags: c#, linq, list

I'd like to replace all null value in my `List<string>` but if don't want to do a foreach loop.

```
List<string> tmpList = new List<string>();
//src is a List<string> where I want to remplace the null by "NULL"
foreach(string s in src) 
{  
    if(s == null) 
    {
        tmpList.Add("NULL");
    }
    else

    {
        tmpList.Add(s);
    }
}
src = tmpList;
```

Do you know a better way to do this ? With LINQ may be ?

Comment: What's wrong with `for (int i = 0; i < src.Count; i++) src[i] = src[i] ?? "NULL";`

Comment: What do you mean by "better"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
src.Select(s => s ?? "NULL").ToList();
```

But what's wrong with using a foreach loop?

Comment: This uses also a loop and it creates a new List which is less efficient than a simple loop.

Comment: foreach internally, plus less inefficient than a simple loop.

Comment: I guess it depends on *why* a loop isn't desired.  If performance isn't a concern and the OP just wants a single line of concise code, this is fine.  (Note that the original code *also* creates a new list, leaving the original list unmodified.  There could be a reason for that not being shared in the question.)

Comment: @EhsanSajjad s ?? "NULL" means: if s is not null, return s, otherwise return "NULL"

Comment: @EhsanSajjad That operator returns the left operand if it is non null, otherwise it return the right one.

Comment: @ken2k: there's nothing more efficient than modifying the original list directly: `for (int i = 0; i < src.Count; i++) src[i] = src[i] ?? "NULL";`. No need for another list which doubles the memory temporarily.

Comment: If he wants to use a simple loop, than he should just do so. for (int i = 0; i < src.Count; i++) if (src[i] == null) src[i] = "NULL";

Comment: @TimSchmelter I definitely agree ;) See my answer (I didn't used ??, but same philosophy)

Comment: These apples are certainly more efficient than your oranges! Seriously, all these solutions have the same efficiency... I mean, the odds which one of these implementation are going to change anything, from user's perspective are very slim (and creating new list, while leaving the old one unchanged could have many advantages). On the other hand, with linq - he can save the query, without creating new list. Did I mention readability and maintainability?

Comment: @TimSchmelter True. You can't use foreach when modifying the list. He used a foreach in the question. I though maybe he disapproved of foreach in general.

Answer (score 1):

```
var list = new List<string>() { null, "test1", "test2" };
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    if (list[i] == null)
    {
        list[i] = "NULL";
    }
}
```

No `foreach`.

---

EDIT:

As no one seems to understand the meaning of this answer: LINQ does a `foreach` loop internally. You want to conditionally modify each item of a list? Then you *have to* enumerate it.

LINQ is here to help us write queries. **Oh wait, this is the Q of LINQ**.

LINQ is NOT here to modify existing lists. Just use a good old `for loop` here. You could of course create a *new list* based on the existing one with modified values (see best-voted answer), but I'm afraid you'll start using LINQ in a wrong way.

Comment: If I were to guess... This still uses a loop, despite the slightly different keyword which creates it.

Comment: @David - "This still uses a loop" - yes, but so does the answer of Dennis_E. Only "hidden". So i don't quite get the downvotes either.

Comment: @Corak: Sure, anything is going to use a loop somewhere.  There's no LINQ in the compiled IL, for example.  I'm just guessing that "just use `for` instead of `foreach`" is *probably* missing the intent of the question and comes across as... unhelpful.

Comment: @David Yeah, I know, but people just don't understand LINQ does a foreach internally, and is less efficient than a simple for loop. OP's didn't want to use foreach, well then, this is the only answer that doesn't use it. Lazy question, lazy answer (but this _actually_ answers the question).

Comment: @ken2k - well... `var index = 0; if (list.Count > index) { list[index] = list[index] ?? "NULL"; } index++; if (list.Count > index) { ... } index++; ...` - no `for` *or* `foreach`... XD

Comment: @ken2k, by which means LINQ uses foreach loop internally (it doesn't.. unless you consider generator blocks to be real loops). How they are less efficient? (I actually know the answer, but without knowing the needs and constraints of OP, you cannot know if it would be more or less efficient). Does it worth the loss of readability and maintainability?

Comment: @ShlomiBorovitz How do you think the LINQ `Select` function works? It internally calls `Enumerable.SelectIterator` which is literally no more than a `foreach`/`yield return`. How is it less efficient? `ToList()` creates a new list, so temporarily doubles the required memory. OP and people that'll read this question should be aware of that, that's the purpose of this answer.

Comment: @ken2k, That "internal foreach" is generator block... it is no more "foreach" than `myList.GetEnumerator()` is "foreach". In the end, maybe you'll have to enumerate the list - but it would be enumerated once... exactly once. Secondly, the memory of another list, could be a constraint. It probably isn't. OP creates new list in his code. Why? We don't know. He might needs another list. Maybe, it would be more desirable to save the query instead of creating new list.. maybe changing the original is more desirable... But being it more memory-efficient isn't making it better.

Comment: @ShlomiBorovitz - "being it more memory-efficient isn't making it better." - well, that's the thing. More memory-efficient *is* better, when memory efficiency is the goal. OP just wants "better" without defining what he means by that. It *seems* like he isn't out for memory efficiency. But then what? Faster? The accepted answer won't be "faster" (it won't be much slower either). More maintainable? Probably. As you said, we don't know.

Comment: @Corak - "OP just wants "better" without defining what he means by that" He does. "better" is without foreach ;) Dennis_E's answer is equivalent to his code, but without foreach... so it's "better"